# Stopping a jQuery animation and reversing

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a move animation that works like this:

```
 function showMessage() 
 {
     $('#message').stop().show().animate({top: '60px'}, 500, 'easeOutExpo');
 }      

 function hideMessage(msg,hide) 
 {
     $('#message').stop().delay(time).animate({ top: '0px' }, 600, 'easeInExpo');
 }
```

The animation moves an item to 60px when shown, and then back to 0px when it hides. The problem is if showMessage starts before hideMessage completes I'll get an ugly jump animation.

What I want is for the showMessage animation to basically reverse the hideMessage animation if it starts before hideMessage was complete.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll want to make sure that animation A is complete before it starts B.

```
 $('#message').stop(true,true).show();
```

Which is saying .stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] ). [Here's the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

You were close!
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnN2d/)

Comment: Your solution is better so I'll accept the answer but it's still not perfect. It retriggers the showMessage animation from the 0px starting point as oppose to stoping the hideMessage (wherever it is in the animation process) and moving back up to 60px. I'm not sure if what I'm requesting is even possible...